# Get messages from erroneous python script run in C# .NET with ArcObjects

Tags: arcpy, arcobjects, .net

I'm trying to implement some error handling into my C# code for my .NET application. I feel like I'm missing something really obvious because I know there has to be a way to do this, but I just can't figure it out. I have a python script I call out to using `gp.Execute()`. If there is an error in the python script and it does not complete, I cannot get the message from it, because any call like `gp.GetMessages()` has to come after the `gp.Execute()` statement, so it never gets hit if the script encounters an error and execution stops in my C# code. How do you get error messages from your scripts? I have also tried to put `gp.GetMessages()` in the catch statement but the `gp` object is considered out of scope there.

My current code:

```
try {
     //stuff here

     //Run PopulatePatches script
     IGeoProcessor2 gp = new GeoProcessorClass();
     gp.AddToolbox(@"C:\Users\mxxx\Desktop\GIS_Testing\HbtatTesting\HabitatMon.tbx");
     IVariantArray parameters = new VarArrayClass();
     parameters.Add(shapefile);
     gp.Execute("PopulatePatches", parameters, null);
     gp.GetMessages(ref sev) //never hits this line if python script fails
}
catch {
     ViewBag.Message = "Failed!";
     return View();
}
```

Lastly, I have gotten rid of the try/catch block and tried to just get the script to play through by doing this:

```
IGeoProcessorResult pResult = gp.Execute("PopulatePatches", parameters, null)
int severity = 2;
string messages = pResult.GetMessages(severity);

//I have also attempted the above line with just straight gp.GetMessages(severity) 
//because I think result objects are null if the tool doesn't execute properly

ViewBag.Message = messages;
return View();
```

It will always stop on the execute call, throwing the general HResult E_FAIL COMException in .NET even though I know the error is a ZeroDivisionError in the script because I purposely put it in there (the code runs perfect in python and my .NET app if I fix the zero division error).

Comment: Just a wild guess: you could try to move the `gp = new GeoProcessorclass()` before `try`, and then call `gp.getMessages()` inside the `catch` block. (In fact, the only thing you want to `try` is the call to `Execute`)

Comment: @Berend If I could upvote you 100 million times, I would. I've been trying to figure this out for ages and that solution works perfectly. I don't know why it didn't occur to me to just move `gp` out into the local scope...

Comment: Good to hear. I'll copy my comment to an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get the messages in the `catch` block, the gp variable needs to be accessible outside `try`.

You could also use `finally` if you want to get the messages regardless of success.

```cs
IGeoProcessor2 gp = new GeoProcessorClass();
gp.AddToolbox(@"C:\Users\mxxx\Desktop\GIS_Testing\HbtatTesting\HabitatMon.tbx");
IVariantArray parameters = new VarArrayClass();
parameters.Add(shapefile);

try 
{
     gp.Execute("PopulatePatches", parameters, null);
}
catch 
{
     ViewBag.Message = "Failed!";
}
finally
{
     var messages = gp.GetMessages(ref sev);
     // Do something useful with messages

     return View();
}
```